# Getting errror when trying to deploy rails 4 application on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I am trying to deploy rails 4 application on heroku but failed & getting below error. Please try to get me out from this issue...

```
       Bundle completed (42.53s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       could not connect to server: Connection refused
       Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
```

Comment: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#troubleshooting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have first set DATABASE_URL environment variable & then again tried to push code to Heroku again. And it worked as all rake compilation done at Heroku side so no more connection to local machine making rake compilation @ .../tmp/bin..... directory.

I got this solution by trying this thing ... :)

Answer (score 0):

TakeAdd the following to your application.rb:

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```